# Installing Varnish Cache 3.0 on Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, varnish, yum

Just a quick question to see if anyone knows how to install Varnish Cache 3.0 on an Amazon EC2 Instance without having to build from source? I have previously installed on many servers running Ubuntu and CentOS, however I'm having trouble with EC2 Instances.

I've updated the repos to include the latest version (https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/redhat), but only some of the packages are comign from varnish-3.0 (varnish-debuginfo.x86_64), whereas some are still coming from amzn-main (varnish.x86_64) after doing yum list.

Does anyone know how to get around this? I've also tried --enablerepo=varnish-3.0 but that still tries to install Varnish 2.1.5

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was something to do with yum repo priorties. So first make you have the plugin installed, with:

```
yum install yum-priorities
```

Then edit /etc/yum.repos.d/varnish.repo adding a line "`priority=1`"

To be safe, run "`yum clean all`", then when you next try "`yum install varnish`" you should get the version from `varnish.repo` rather than Amazon's default.